# Storing values securely in mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, security, cakephp, innodb

I am creating a CakePHP web application. Obviously passwords are stored with a hash, but is there a way to securely store values of other fields that will be retrieved? I'm not talking anything as sensitive as credit cards, but SSN's and Salaries would be stored. I'm not sure what the standard for storing information such as this is, or if CakePHP has a helper for it. I am using InnoDB as the engine.

Comment: What you are seeking is reversible encryption rather than hashing. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html

Comment: In theory isn't any encryption reversible though if a hacker were to get into the server and find the SALT? (Edit, just realized user2246676 said exactly that).

Comment: @LukeSapan There is no "salt" with encryption (a salt is *not* a secret). There is a *secret key* (think of "encryption password"). And yes, if someone learned that secret key (in which case it wouldn't be a secret) .. then they can learn all your secrets. This differs from a hash/salt (which are designed to *not*) be reversible. Storing only the hashed SSN (like a password) would only be useful for comparing known input; but useless on retrieving the original SSN values.

Comment: Ultimately though, assuming user accounts are configured to have limited access and only vital ones do have access, using the core security encryption would be the best approach?

Comment: @LukeSapan Encryption prevents against offline access to data (i.e. from a backup or direct filesystem access in which case DB permissions/roles are not applied) or capturing values in-flight (i.e. going over the network "raw"). However, if the application has access to view the data and the secret key to decrypt the data, and someone has access to the application .. compartmentalization (e.g. only part X of the application when run as user U can access the sensitive data) is another important layer.

Comment: In my opinion server security is more important than database encryption. I am happy with my nightly not encrypted database-dumps,  which I can edit as text, when I know no one can access the server remote, unless they are using a browser and using port 80, _or_ is located at the same local network. This is real security. I cannot even do it myself from home.

Comment: @davidkonrad All in it's place ;) But I agree that there is little point closing the screen door while leaving the safe open in the parlor.

Comment: @user2246674, see it as a kind of "paradox". If you need to encrypt data, when you cannot have trust to your own security. If the security is allright, when you not need encryption. I can understand if a customer wants encryption, for one reason or another, but it is still the same "paradox". If ypu have access to the server remote, as admin, you are likely to get over the encryption as well.

Comment: If your information is only needed sparsely (like once per month or something to calculate wages) then you can store it encrypted and have a trusted user type in the password to access it before the data is parsed. This way even if someone has the DB dump and the program code they can't get anywhere. An alternative to that, less secure though, is to again not store the password anyplace other than memory and hope that noone has the time and security privileges to access it from RAM. Of course everytime you reboot you will need to type it in or else nothing will work.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not talking anything as sensitive as credit cards, but SSN's and Salaries would be stored.

CakePHP might not directly support this, but if you use [CipherSweet](https://github.com/paragonie/ciphersweet/), you can not only encrypt sensitive information before storing it, but still use these fields (indirectly) in your SELECT queries.

For example, you could encrypt the user's SSNs and salaries, and then maintain independent indexes of:

- The user's SSN
- The last 4 digits of the user's SSN
- The user's salary

Additionally, CipherSweet exclusively uses [authenticated encryption](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken) and ciphertexts are [securely randomized](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059609995/crypto-noobs-1-initialization-vectors). Under the hood, it [goes out of its way to ensure each field and index has a unique key](https://ciphersweet.paragonie.com/internals/key-hierarchy).

### CipherSweet Example

#### Setup

```
<?php
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Backend\FIPSCrypto;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\BlindIndex;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\CipherSweet;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\KeyProvider\StringProvider;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Transformation\LastFourDigits;

$cipher = new CipherSweet(
    new StringProvider(
        str_repeat("\xff", 32)
    ),
    new FIPSCrypto()
);

$ER = (new EncryptedRow($cipher, 'users'))
    ->addIntegerField('salary')
    ->addTextField('ssn')
    ->addBlindIndex(
        'ssn',
        new BlindIndex('ssn_idx', [], 32)
    )
    ->addBlindIndex(
        'salary',
        new BlindIndex('salary_idx', [], 16)
    )
    ->addBlindIndex(
        'ssn',
        new BlindIndex(
            'ssn_last4_idx',
            [new LastFourDigits()],
            16
        )
    )
;
```

#### Encrypting and SELECTing

Ciphertexts are randomized, but indexes are static. Let's encrypt a user's records (let's call her Alice).

```
$plaintext = [
    'username' => 'alice',
    'ssn' => '123-456-7890',
    'salary' => 135000
];
list($row, $indexes) = $ER->prepareRowForStorage($plaintext);
$decrypted = $ER->decryptRow($row);
var_dump($row, $indexes, $decrypted);
```

This would produce something like:

```
array(3) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(5) "alice"
  ["ssn"]=>
  string(149) "fips:sZU-A5GvF0vrXFTuXJMoIjKrr3HAO83dSsfPXajlTkg7-ce9goff4TGsbnsmBje77USijlEp3xR0sDTo2gekZEtzoDaoNUbBcm57Va5DiFztHEV2QaREEzCdU-uV5MOg3dpxoxfq116ZRlMA"
  ["salary"]=>
  string(145) "fips:hoSB4beTtcMbOum2RoPYE8PSagvCDoeGq2mjiONm_mj6A_wobXxrMjb_x_Z-u7oMVg2TvpzXbxdN7JP0XGm6ITwefMMF5Jhq7rbYjAX38SWcCYcYyryHmBr5WgVFOJM-bvhuhAOEi6o="
}
array(3) {
  ["ssn_idx"]=>
  string(8) "3cc637b3"
  ["ssn_last4_idx"]=>
  string(4) "bb0c"
  ["salary_idx"]=>
  string(4) "5879"
}
array(3) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(5) "alice"
  ["ssn"]=>
  string(12) "123-456-7890"
  ["salary"]=>
  int(135000)
}
```

If you were to also compare this with another employee's records (let's call him Bob), you'd see similar indexes:

```
$plaintext = [
    'username' => 'bob',
    'ssn' => '456-123-7890',
    'salary' => 135001
];
```

You would see something similar:

```
array(3) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(3) "bob"
  ["ssn"]=>
  string(149) "fips:yauOEc7jF529frr7BYf16N7WNDs0koRj5yX3RhyCVPacBWPr_G8KltBSjVkNobIu2sfeWeLFCRBr1p0VHoNCADd4PPcJa6IciKjU8-K5v7Znt93g-NNlhaMzPOLqE9UVob9YxKpMb-9ZEzcW"
  ["salary"]=>
  string(145) "fips:X64DBCbralyoNuE2sZvK_HjkRhIdrnNbVY2qaHfM1s6YmMUjNnRHVS0mq_SYS3Vo982BL72RMumhtPLwa4MoewOD8ycgbLhRx74-CjyFXdqFbPkEoeLESCBu471O-19Dx-4JJVGROHM="
}
array(3) {
  ["ssn_idx"]=>
  string(8) "6950e82d"
  ["ssn_last4_idx"]=>
  string(4) "bb0c"
  ["salary_idx"]=>
  string(4) "0287"
}
array(3) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(3) "bob"
  ["ssn"]=>
  string(12) "456-123-7890"
  ["salary"]=>
  int(135001)
}
```

Some details worth noting:

- Alice's `ssn_last4_idx` and Bob's `ssn_last4_idx` were identical (`bb0c` for this key), because the `LastFourDigits` transform was applied.
- Alice and Bob's SSNs and salaries differed, and therefore, their literal indexes (`ssn_idx` and `salary_idx`) differed.

So if your select query looks like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE ssn_last4_idx = ?"
["bb0c"]
```

...you'll get two rows (one for Alice, one for Bob), since the last 4 digits of their SSNs are the same.

But if you were to do use this instead:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE ssn_last4_idx = ? AND salary_idx = ?"
["bb0c", "0287"]
```

You'd only get Bob. Similarly:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE ssn_idx = ?"
["3cc637b3"]
```

...would uniquely identify Alice.

### TL;DR

Implementing [searchable encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/05/building-searchable-encrypted-databases-with-php-and-sql) is a nontrivial undertaking, but there's no need to reinvent the wheel.

CipherSweet isn't built into CakePHP, but there's no reason its inclusion couldn't be proposed in a future version.